Shift part of row in dataframe to new row
I have a dataframe (pandas) that I want to transform for displaying purposes.
Therefore I want to shift some parts of the dataframe to new rows like below :
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift1 col_not_to_shift2
0   a1   a2           a3                a4                a5
1   b1   b2          NaN                b4               NaN
2   c1   c2           c3                c4                c5

I would like to obtain the following dataframe where a new row is created for the value (if not NaN) in the column to shift (unique), duplicating the data description contained in col1 and col2 and keeping the columns that I don't want to shift even if they contain NaNs:
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift1 col_not_to_shift2
0   a1   a2           a3               NaN               NaN
1   a1   a2          NaN                a4                a4
2   b1   b2          NaN                b4               NaN
3   c1   c2           c3               NaN               NaN
4   c1   c2          NaN                c4                c4

I tried looking at pd.shift but was not able to make it work.
Here is a piece of code to produce the dataframe :
data = {"col1": ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'col2': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
        'col_to_shift': ['a3', np.NaN, 'c3'],
        'col_not_to_shift1': ['a4', 'b4', 'c4'],
        'col_not_to_shift2': ['a5', np.NaN, 'c5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Can you clarify how this would generalize if you have more columns?

That's a fair point, I clarified because my example did not fully reproduced my dataframe (I can have NaNs in the columns that I don't want to shift)

thanks for clarifying, then my first approach wouldn't work but the other two would (the dropna='all' is important)

It is still great to have the other variants in case someone's dataframe does not have NaNs like mine, thanks

One option using concat:

split the DataFrame in two parts keeping grouping columns for both
drop the empty rows with dropna
sort the rows with sort_values and a stable sort algorithm

group = ['col1', 'col2']
cols  = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('not_to_shift')]

out = (pd.concat([df.drop(columns=cols).dropna(axis=0),
                  df[cols.union(group)].dropna(axis=0)
                 ])
         .sort_values(by=group, kind='stable')
      )

Output:
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift
0   a1   a2           a3              NaN
0   a1   a2          NaN               a4
1   b1   b2          NaN               b4
2   c1   c2           c3              NaN
2   c1   c2          NaN               c4

Variant using the index as group (this does not maintain the original index):
group = ['col1', 'col2']
not_shift = ['col_not_to_shift']

tmp = df.set_index(group)
out = (pd.concat([tmp.drop(columns=not_shift), tmp[not_shift]])
         .dropna(how='all').sort_index(kind='stable')
         .reset_index()
      )

Or by defining the list of columns to shift/not-shift:
shift = ['col_to_shift']
not_shift = ['col_not_to_shift1', 'col_not_to_shift2']

out = (pd.concat([df.drop(columns=not_shift),
                  df.drop(columns=shift)
                 ])
         .dropna(subset=shift+not_shift, how='all')
         .sort_index(kind='stable')
      )

Output:
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift1 col_not_to_shift2
0   a1   a2           a3               NaN               NaN
0   a1   a2          NaN                a4                a5
1   b1   b2          NaN                b4               NaN
2   c1   c2           c3               NaN               NaN
2   c1   c2          NaN                c4                c5


With the clarification in the question, the second variant works as expected for me.

try this
df1 = df[~df.col_to_shift.isnull()].drop(columns=['col_not_to_shift1', 'col_not_to_shift2'])
df2 = df[~df.col_to_shift.isnull()].drop(columns='col_to_shift')
pd.concat([df1, df2, df[df.col_to_shift.isnull()]], ignore_index=True).set_index(['col1', 'col2']).sort_index().reset_index()


Code
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
out = pd.concat([
    df[cols + ['col_to_shift']].dropna(),
    df[cols + ['col_not_to_shift']].dropna()
]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

out:
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift
0   a1   a2           a3              NaN
1   a1   a2          NaN               a4
2   b1   b2          NaN               b4
3   c1   c2           c3              NaN
4   c1   c2          NaN               c4


Thanks, this works fine if col_not_to_shift does not contain a NaN value, but it is the case in my dataframe, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Try this:
((v:=df.set_index(['col1','col2']))
.set_axis([v.columns != 'col_to_shift',v.columns],axis=1)
.stack(level=0)
.droplevel(-1)
.reindex(v.columns,axis=1)
.reset_index())

Output:
  col1 col2 col_to_shift col_not_to_shift1 col_not_to_shift2
0   a1   a2           a3               NaN               NaN
1   a1   a2          NaN                a4                a5
2   b1   b2          NaN                b4               NaN
3   c1   c2           c3               NaN               NaN
4   c1   c2          NaN                c4                c5

